# Custom API responses

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently trying to create an API handler that will ensure that all my requests follow the same template using express in Node JS. So I have defined the structure of the response and registered it as middleware in my express application. I am however unable to get the responses to work.

I have tried importing express into the external class for it to use the `res` parameter for the middleware. I have also tried it without. I have tried expressing it with middleware parameters such as `(req, res, next)` which didn't work either. So I am unsure what to try next.

The external handler is as follows:

```
exports.success = (message, results, statusCode) => {
    return {
        message,
        error: false,
        code: statusCode,
        results
    };
};
```

I however tried the following as well which didn't work:

```
exports.success = (message, results, statusCode) => {
    return res.json({
       message,
       error: false,
       code: statusCode,
       results
   });
};
```

I tried this as well which didn't work:

```
exports.success = (message, results, statusCode) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({
            message,
            error: false,
            code: statusCode,
            results
        });
        next();
    }
};
```

I have implemented it in the middleware as follows:

```
this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.success = responseHandler.success;
    next();
});
```

Is it not possible to implement what I am trying (which I doubt)? I have a feeling I am just returning the wrong thing but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: What happens when the code is run? Do you get an error? What's the expected output vs. the output you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get this working, I've tested a simple version of what you're trying to achieve.

I've used a [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) call to ensure the context is correct for the success() call, also we'll use the function declaration rather than an arrow function in the response-handler module for the same reason.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const responseHandler = require('./response-handler.js')

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.success = responseHandler.success.bind(res);
    next();
});

app.get('/success', function(req,res,error) {
    res.success("Success - yay!!", { foo: 'bar' }, 418);
})

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

**response-handler.js**

```
exports.success = function(message, results, statusCode) {
    this.json({
        message,
        error: false,
        code: statusCode,
        results
    });
};
```

Comment: Great, glad to be of some help :-)